# Как в MySQL найти непрерывные последовательности?

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите с определением непрерывных последовательностей.
Имеется таблица с датами и на каждую дату что то случалось или не случалось. Если что то случалось на протяжении какого то промежутка времени, то нужно указать дату начала и дату окончания.
На скрине пример:

[image: Пример]

Comment: ну а где данные "что случилось"?

Answer (score 0):

Если версия MySQL поддерживает оконные функции, то можно попробовать использовать их.
Таблица названа q1261234, замените на свое.

```
SELECT
    y.id,
    MIN(y.date) d_start,
    MAX(y.date) d_end
FROM (
    SELECT
        x.id,
        x.date,
        SUM(x.flag) OVER (PARTITION BY x.id ORDER BY x.date) grp_flag
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            CASE
                WHEN LAG(var) over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) <> var THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END flag
        FROM q1261234
    ) x
    WHERE var = 1
) y
GROUP BY y.id, grp_flag;
```