# непрерывная последовательность sql

Tags: sql

в общем сам вопрос в теме вопроса, нашёл здесь такой ответ :
[Как в MySQL найти непрерывные последовательности?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1261234/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-mysql-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8)

Но что если дата будет дальше повторяться , вопрос такой: всё хорошо но как сделать флаги уникальные?
давайте представим у нас идут сигналы, и значения, и дата и время сигнала
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот в таком случае группировка даёт ужасный результат как быть?

Comment: Совершенно стандартная задача. Gaps and islands прозывается. Ответ по ссылке не читайте - там баловство, а не решение. Ну и см. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункты 5 и 3, а также [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120).